# Boost X3: Can a variant member be avoided in disjunctions?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I'd like to parse `string | (string, int)` and store it in a structure that defaults the `int` component to some value.  The attribute of such a construction in X3 is a `variant<string, tuple<string, int>>`.  I was thinking I could have a `struct` that takes either a `string` or a `(string, int)` to automagically be populated:

```
    struct bar
    {
        bar (std::string x = "", int y = 0) : baz1 {x}, baz2 {y} {}

        std::string          baz1;
        int                  baz2;
    };

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT (disj::ast::bar, baz1, baz2)
```

and then simply have:

```
    const x3::rule<class bar, ast::bar> bar = "bar";
    using x3::int_;
    using x3::ascii::alnum;

    auto const bar_def = (+(alnum) | ('(' >> +(alnum) >> ',' >> int_ >> ')')) >> ';';

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(bar);
```

However this does not work:

```
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/core/detail/parse_into_container.hpp:139:59: error: static assertion failed: Expecting a single element fusion sequence
  139 |             static_assert(traits::has_size<Attribute, 1>::value,
```

Setting `baz2` to an `optional` does not help.  One way to solve this is to have a `variant` field or inherit from that type:

```
    struct string_int {
        std::string s;
        int i;
    };

    struct foo {
        boost::variant<std::string, string_int>  var;
    };

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT (disj::ast::string_int, s, i)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT (disj::ast::foo, var)
```

(For some reason, I have to use `boost::variant` instead of `x3::variant` for `operator<<` to work; also, using `std::pair` or `tuple` for `string_int` does not work, but `boost::fusion::deque` does.)  One can then equip `foo` somehow to get the  string and integer.

**Question:** What is the proper, clean way to do this in X3?  Is there a more natural way than this second option and equipping `foo` with accessors?

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8077b4776536858a)</kbd>**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly the wording in the [x3 section](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/spirit_x3/quick_reference/operator.html) is exceedingly sparse and allows it (contrast the [Qi section](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/alternative.html#spirit.qi.reference.operator.alternative.attributes)). A quick test confirms it:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02f0e16eb7a17ada)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

template <typename Expr>
std::string inspect(Expr const& expr) {
    using A = typename x3::traits::attribute_of<Expr, x3::unused_type>::type;
    return boost::core::demangle(typeid(A).name());
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << inspect(x3::double_ | x3::int_) << "\n";       // variant expected
    std::cout << inspect(x3::int_ | "bla" >> x3::int_) << "\n"; // variant "understandable"
    std::cout << inspect(x3::int_ | x3::int_) << "\n";          // variant suprising:
}
```

Prints

```
boost::variant<double, int>
boost::variant<int, int>
boost::variant<int, int>
```

### All Hope Is Not Lost

In your specific case you could trick the system:

```
auto const bar_def =                              //
    (+x3::alnum >> x3::attr(-1)                   //
    | '(' >> +x3::alnum >> ',' >> x3::int_ >> ')' //
    ) >> ';';
```

Note how we "inject" an int value for the first branch. That satisfies the attribute propagation gods:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c13491296762743)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace disj::ast {
    struct bar {
        std::string x;
        int         y;
    };
    using boost::fusion::operator<<;
} // namespace disj::ast

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(disj::ast::bar, x, y)

namespace disj::parser {
    const x3::rule<class bar, ast::bar> bar = "bar";

    auto const bar_def =                              //
        (+x3::alnum >> x3::attr(-1)                   //
        | '(' >> +x3::alnum >> ',' >> x3::int_ >> ')' //
        ) >> ';';

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(bar)
}

namespace disj {
    void run_tests() {
        for (std::string const input : {
                 "",
                 ";",
                 "bla;",
                 "bla, 42;",
                 "(bla, 42);",
             }) {

            ast::bar val;
            auto f = begin(input), l = end(input);

            std::cout << "\n" << quoted(input) << " -> ";

            if (phrase_parse(f, l, parser::bar, x3::space, val)) {
                std::cout << "Parsed: " << val << "\n";
            } else {
                std::cout << "Failed\n";
            }

            if (f!=l) {
                std::cout << " -- Remaining " << quoted(std::string_view(f, l)) << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    disj::run_tests();
}
```

Prints

```
"" -> Failed

";" -> Failed
 -- Remaining ";"

"bla;" -> Parsed: (bla -1)

"bla, 42;" -> Failed
 -- Remaining "bla, 42;"

"(bla, 42);" -> Parsed: (bla 42)
```

---

¹ just [today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69253293/boost-spirit-x3-how-to-process-in-case-of-an-optional-that-can-be-nullopt-in-a/69255251#69255251)

Comment: As a matter of style, I'd suggest making the `int` optional in the struct to avoid magic values (-1, in my answer example): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aaf395666e0b7667

Comment: That is fantastic sehe, positively amazing—and sure, I was expecting you'd be answering, but that fast, it's just crazy.  Thanks a lot!  I was going down a rabbit hole trying to understand why some stuff works with `x3::variant` but not with `boost::variant` or `std::variant`, so I'm very happy this madness can be safely ignored (turning to other madnesses, certainly).   I did not spot `x3::attr` in "Auxiliary Parsers" in the doc, that's a nice trick!  And what a coincidence that someone would ask a similar question today…!  Thanks again :-)